# Is there a search name list example?

Tags: c

I want to create a code (using standard C) to search a name list (1000 or more records).
Note that the list is not in order and length. And the input name may request again.

For example:

```
const char * student_name[] = {
"Ann",
"Ada",
"Anna",
};
```

How efficient search (if input = "Anna")?
I tried to find an example, but no success.
If you have examples, please share it with me for reference.

I tried to search("Anna"), but the result is "Ann". If it is necessary to compare all records in a list, the process (1000pcs input & 1000pcs record) will be a very long time.

Comment: This question is too broad. If you plan to search the name list more than once, you should either sort it and use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) method, or use some sort of [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: Thanks & note. I am a beginner in programming. Please let me have a chance to be you.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Jason, I am looking for a searching programming example(s). If you see it on the internet(open source), please share it with me.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://codeforwin.org/2018/05/c-program-to-search-an-element-in-linked-list.html ?

Comment: If the data is not sorted, then you cannot reliably do better than a linear search.  When the item searched for does not exist in the name list, that means comparing every item with the desired one.  When the item is present, on average, it probably scans about half the list to find the item, assuming random order and random names to be found.  To do better, you need a more complex data structure — a heap, a hash table, or a sorted array are plausible candidates.

Comment: stackoverflow is NOT a free coding service.  Please generate your own code, then (if it does not work as desired) post a question about your code, the includes what the problem is (usually a descrepancy between desired output and actual output  I.E. post a [mcve] so we can duplicate your problem and help you debug it.

Comment: I am a beginner on it and see many people say that. On many web sites, they have some examples of a tutorial. I tried but can't find what I want, so ask in here. Initially, I think here have many experts & will to share(like a teacher). However, I am disappointed.